# Inequality $\Big\| f_1(x) \overline{f_2(x)} |f_3 (x)|\Big\|_{H^1(\mathbb R)} \le C\|f(x)\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R)}^2 \|f(x)\|_{H^1(\mathbb R)}$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

For complex-valued functions $f_1, f_2, f_3:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$, I want to know that the following inequality holds:
$$
\Big\| f_1(x) \overline{f_2(x)} |f_3 (x)|\Big\|_{H^1(\mathbb R)}
\le C\|f(x)\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R)}^2 \|f(x)\|_{H^1(\mathbb R)}
$$
where $\|\cdot \|_{H^1}$ is the standard Sobolev norm of the order $1$ and
$\|f(x)\|_{H^1} = \sum_{k=1}^3 \|f_k (x)\|_{H^1}$, 
$\|f(x)\|_{L^\infty} = \sum_{k=1}^3 \|f_k (x)\|_{L^\infty}$.

Comment: I overrode the closure of this question due to some strangeness in the post's edit history: the OP seemed to have blanked out the post for a few minutes just now and then quickly reverted. Most of the closure votes were cast in those few minutes when the post is non-sense. (To Kurulata: please don't do that in the future. If you register your account you will gain the ability to delete your questions _properly_.)

Comment: As to your question: apply the product rule for derivatives and put the term with the derivative in $L^2$ while the other two in $L^\infty$ using Holder inequality.

Comment: @WillieWong The strangeness did not end there; there is a [second copy](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/908776/) of same post.